# Selenium vs. Jenkins, how to schedule via Jenkins running webdriver java code

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, executable-jar

can someone explain how I can schedule a webdriver java code. currently it runs and open firfox and do some operations.

Jenkins is installed and ready.

I am kind of new to selenium, is it also possible to make a jar file from the webdriver code? This might be also an option, right?

Thanks in advance. 
Cheers
Nzoro

Comment: Step 1: Figure out how to run the tests from command line (without Jenkins). Step 2: Create Jenkins job, which does what you just did from command line.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are having a problem with. Please add details of what you have done, what works, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I can run the jar file on the shell without any problem. When it comes to jenkins I am not able to make it run. 

I am running all on Ubuntu 14.04. No issues with Jenkins, only that I am getting problems with running the xvNC, since as I understood that this is needed to open a firefox session. 

Is there a step by step way of how I need to set jenkins? Which exact Add ons is needed etc. I know about all the other funcionality of jenkins but only the firefox browser does not open because of the nodes. I searched via google, but did not find a proper answer. 

thanks again.

Comment: do you have an idea? How can I proceed with the jenkins issue? I mean it should be possible to run shell command under jenkins? why is this not opening automatically the firefox session. strange ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make your WebDriver-based java code a standalone java application. In this case it will be a .jar file with one entry-point(main method).

Then you can simply run your java programm from jenkins by simply configure a job which run it from command line.

But usually selenium tests ran from jenkins is a much more complex task cause it uses unit test frameworks for writing test such as TestNG or JUnit.

Try to read a bit more about best practices of writing tests using selenium and then go to integrate it with continuous integration tool like jenkins.